# docker push of windows container image to GitHub package repository failed

Tags: github, github-actions, github-for-windows, github-package-registry

I have a dotnet core web app built on windows using GitHub Actions workflow steps. The last step is to build and push the container to GitHub packages (using docker build and docker push commands).

docker push of windows container image to GitHub packages always fails with message below:

```
denied: No matching package_file with sha256 "b9e6fec25718aef5ed18d499b27e43adb524f9ee4f2eb3f0fffaea018e7e86b0" found in repository "myrepo/dotnet-ci".
```

Is windows container not supported in GitHub packages?

I am successful if I use linux for GitHub Actions to build the dotnet core app for linux, build and push linux container to GitHub packages.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it appears to be the case that Windows images are not supported by the GitHub registry: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-docker-for-use-with-github-packages

> **Note**: When installing or publishing a docker image, GitHub Packages does not currently support foreign layers, such as Windows images.